# How is the use of java reflection api java.lang.reflect.get* is not safe?

Tags: java, source-code

Below is the code which is making a private field of a class accessible using `setAccessible` method of java reflection and getting the field value using java.lang.reflect.get method, finally setting is in another object.

```
A a = new A();

Field[] field = b.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for(Field f : field) {

  f.setAccessible(true);
  Object fval = f.get(b);

  if(fval != null){
      a.set(f.getName(), fval);
  } 
}
```

How does the code `f.get(b)` cause a security risk, assuming `b` is coming from some untrusted source ?

Comment: Where is this code used? Where does `b` come from? Why do you suspect there is a security risk here?

Comment: This code is being used to populate one object private field values in another object which is being persisted into a mongoDB. b is an object of a class which is populated using the user provided values.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481862/how-to-limit-setaccessible-to-only-legitimate-uses) link from stack overflow might be able to shed some light on the issue, for those still interested in the answer. OP is probably using a code review software such as HP Fortify.